# Debian Squeeze Slow SMB/Samba Write Speeds

Tags: debian-squeeze, server-message-block, network-speed

Arch: x86_64

OS: Debian

Sub-Version: Squeeze

Prev Speed: 3-5MB

Current Speed: 1MB

Connection: WIFI

WIFI Speed: 150Mbps

I have been Google'in and testing for hours using the same file. I was getting 3-4 and now its 1 or less.

Comment: I believe the title is self explanatory

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that 1 megabyte per second transfer speed is much different than 1 megabit per second transfers. 150 megabits per second is about 18 megabytes per second but that is if you are actually getting the whole 150 megabits per second in the first place. This speed isnt bad for wireless. Step up to a 300mbps router and you may see 2-4 Mb/sec.

Comment: I was getting 3-4 and now it dropped to 1 or less